# Onclick apply to padding and movement of button

Tags: jquery, css, padding

I gave an anchor element a box shadow, and on **:active** I make the box-shadow disappear and the button itself moves to give the illusion of being pressed down.

The thing is, I want both the **padding** and the **original area** to be part of the click action.

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GXxKN/) and my code for when the button is active:

```
.uploadButton:active {
    top: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #393939, 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);    
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The padding and the 'original area', or content-box, are already part of the clickable area.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to generate a click event on the area of the box-shadow, which is I think what you meant.

The way I would try to do what you want is to wrap your button in a bigger, transparent element, which will get the click event and add an '.active' class to your `.uploadButton` when it is clicked.

Comment: That's what I was reserving for a backup, anywho, just went with it.

Also using no z-index for the outer object and using a negative z-index for the inner lets you place the parent above the child.

Comment: Rrr.... this doesn't work, because if it's in another element the button ends up invisible.

Comment: maybe dont put it inside the other element, just superimposed on top of it, but after it in the dom.